# cannot find symbol : LegendItem() in org.jfree.chart.LegendItem

Tags: java, awt, jfreechart

i using the following line in my java program

```
LegendItem item1 = new LegendItem("US", "US", "US", "US",
                new Rectangle(10, 10), new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f,
                new Color(16, 89, 172), 0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(201, 201, 244)));
```

and using "jfreechart-1.0.13.jar" file and getting this error

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   constructor LegendItem(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.awt.Rectangle,java.awt.GradientPaint)
  location: class org.jfree.chart.LegendItem
```

but in the jar file in class org.jfree.chart.LegendItem.class i have seen the constructor with the parameters i am using.
i am using net beans6.9.1 ide . i am not able to find the reason for this.
if any one can help me please
Thanks
Yugal

Comment: compiles fine here. Are you sure you don't have a classpath problem or something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiles & Executes fine , with [`jfreechart-1.0.3.jar`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jfree/jfreechart/1.0.3/jfreechart-1.0.3.jar)  in classpath

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import org.jfree.chart.LegendItem;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        LegendItem item1 = new LegendItem("US", "US", "US", "US",
                new Rectangle(10, 10), new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f,
                new Color(16, 89, 172), 0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(201, 201, 244)));

        System.out.println(item1.getSeriesIndex());
    }
}
```

Comment: i have Compiled & Executed this app with "jfreechart-1.0.3.jar" in classpath. it is compiled successfully but when i run it generates output 0 (zero). thanks

Comment: @Yugal yes it is what it should do , anyways as your problem has been solved , you can upvote `&` / `|`  mark it as answer as it is for you

Comment: i have added three objects of LegendItem (ie item1, item2,item3)and it is giving output 0 (zero) for all objects. why it is not generating its series index number? thanks

Comment: @Yugal that is another question ,should be posted under different title